# Обрезаются данные PHP в массиве POST

Tags: ajax, php

Через Аякс отправляются данные php скрипту:

```
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      dataType: "json",
      data: {data : data, comment : comment},
.....
```

Перед отправкой вывожу значение переменной data:

```
alert(data);
```

Получаю:

> 4KyM6nMwZmStwonvGLYVN8CqM8HU99CCkTgkr5ucUUMy0gsjp4lg4dRvE0nao3MeXYhlsYYqtY8nO5DlJfMXOw==

На сервере вывожу переменную: v

```
ar_dump($_POST['data']);
```

Получаю:

> 4KyM nMwZmStw

Почему данные обрезаются?

**Обновление**

Обрезает до 13 символов. Но ради эксперимента в js перед отправкой переопределил переменную data. Данные пришли без обрезания. Переменные в `php.ini` на POST размерность проверил - не должно стать поводом

Comment: попробуйте перед отправкой сделать data = encodeURIComponent(data)

Comment: Интересно то, что переменная comment приходит полностью

Comment: data: {data : data, comment : comment}

А у Вас не конфликтуют переменные? Был бы я на месте скрипта, вывел бы подобную фигню в результате этой строки (если значение comment='blo'):

    data: {4KyM6nMwZmStwonvGLYVN8CqM8HU99CCkTgkr5ucUUMy0gsjp4lg4dRvE0nao3MeXYhlsYYqtY8nO5DlJfMXOw== : 4KyM6nMwZmStwonvGLYVN8CqM8HU99CCkTgkr5ucUUMy0gsjp4lg4dRvE0nao3MeXYhlsYYqtY8nO5DlJfMXOw==, blo : blo}

А еще посмотрите, может у Вас до отправки данных переменную data что-то изменяет?)

Comment: @fremail, здесь нет никакой ошибки, можеет в консоли сами проверить.

Comment: @Oleg Ponomarchuk в консоли в сетевой вкладке смотрели что именно отправляется ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Простой способ узнать, кто режет, посмотреть на  file_get_contents('php://input'),  там лежит тело запроса до любых обработок php